# SQL0628N with MODIFIES SQL DATA when creating a table function

Tags: db2, db2-luw, sql-pl

I am trying to encapsulate the functionality from this [sample code here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dsm-last-row-count-procedure-return-cumulative-number-rows-fetched),  inside a Table-Function.

I can run the sample alone without any problem.

But when I create a table function, just with a single call to OPEN_CURSOR , I receive **SQL0577N**

```
CREATE FUNCTION ROW_CHECKSUM
    ( IN sSchema      VARCHAR(128) ,
    IN sTable         VARCHAR(128) ,
    IN sColumnList    VARCHAR(1024) ,
    IN sWhere         VARCHAR(1023),
    IN iRows          INTEGER
    )
    RETURNS TABLE (ROW_PK_VALUES VARCHAR(3000), CHECKSUM INTEGER  )
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SPECIFIC ROW_CHECKSUM
    --NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    --MODIFIES SQL DATA
    --NOT DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE iCheckSum INTEGER ;
    DECLARE sKyes     VARCHAR(1024) ;

    DECLARE iCursor INTEGER;
    DECLARE sQuery  VARCHAR(32000) ;

    SET sQuery = 'SELECT ' || sColumnList || ' FROM "' || sSchema || '"."' || sTable || '" WHERE ' || sWhere || ' FETCH FIRST ' || TO_CHAR(iRows) || ' ONLY' ;

    CALL DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR(iCursor);
    --CALL DBMS_SQL.PARSE(iCursor, sQuery, DBMS_SQL.native) ;
    --PIPE (sKeys, iCheckSum) ;
    --PIPE ('abcd', 1234) ;

    RETURN ;
END


----
SQL0577N  User defined routine "DB2ADMIN.ROW_CHECKSUM" (specific name "")
attempted to modify data but was not defined as MODIFIES SQL DATA.  LINE
NUMBER=33.  SQLSTATE=38002
```

it seems, OPEN_CURSOR demands to have the MODIFY SQL DATA specified..  ok..  let's go!
But, when I specify it, then I get the following error, instead:

```
SQL0628N  Multiple or conflicting keywords involving the "MODIFIES SQL DATA"
clause are present.  LINE NUMBER=33.  SQLSTATE=42613
```

The error details for -628 error is too generic and does not help me to determine what's really going on here.

I need to perform dynamic SQL queries using DBMS_SQL module,  and return the result set using PIPE , like this [other sample here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-pipe).

I have been reading spread documentations the entire day..  and so far was not able to determine exactly what rule I am violating.

Also,  found some inconsistencies on documentation, which I don't understand:
This [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-restrictions-sql),  says:

- SQL table functions cannot contain compiled compound statements.

While,  the Rules from [RETURN statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-return) says the opposite, and matches with PIPE sample code:

- In an SQL table function using a compound SQL (compiled) statement, an expression, NULL, or fullselectcannot be specified. Rows are returned from the function using the PIPE statement and the RETURN statement is required as the last statement to execute when the function exits (SQLSTATE 2F005).

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the note about the `MODIFIES SQL DATA` in the [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-function-sql-scalar-table-row) statement description:

> 4 Valid only for compiled scalar function definition and an inlined
> table function definition.

But you can't use `PIPE` in an inlined function.
So, you want to use different functionalities, which can't be used together.
The inconsistency you found in the documentation is not related to you problem.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to be a dead-end..  hard do find these kind of details on these notes.  Thanks for pointing it out. Actually I will jsut read information.  I will not change anything,,  not sure why the OPEN_CURSOR() demmads the MODIFIES SQL DATA level. :-(   This seems to be an overlook or over protection on OPEN_CURSOR definition.  it could have additional parameters to tell if the cursor will be read-only or not. Anyway Thanks @Mark Barinstein